# How can I get my text file data to display in listbox?

Tags: vb.net, text, listbox, display

I have an issue that I would like some help with.

I am trying to open a file dialog, select text file, and then display text in listbox.

I have the following code. It opens dialog, but won't display text in listbox.

Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImportKeywordList.Click

    Dim oReader As StreamReader
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True
    OpenFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        oReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
        ListBox1.Text = oReader.ReadToEnd()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure its opening a file?

Comment: Listbox display text through the Items collection not through the Text property that is present just cause it derives from the base Control class

Comment: Thanks, but can you possible dumb that statement way down for me?

Comment: It's not opening a file, it's opening the windows explorer box

Answer (score 1):

Listbox display text through the Items collection not through the Text property. In a ListBox the [Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) represent the text of the currently selected item

An example could  be written in this way

```
....
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Using oReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, True)
        While oReader.Peek <> -1
           ListBox1.Items.Add(oReader.ReadLine())
        End While
    End Using
End If
....
```